# Is there a way to create object with common value as key and assigning the common objects as array values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say i have an array of four objects

```
var data = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 2, b: 4}, 
   {a: 1, b: 6}, 
   {a: 2, b: 9}
];
```

And i want to create an object say
Taking common value and passing it as key and assigning the value ob common objects to an array like below

```
Const treat = {

    1:[{a:1,b:2} {a:1,b:6}],
    2:[{a:2,b:4} {a:2,b:9}]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of what you want. You can research different array methods such as [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to see other ways to obtain similar results.

```js
var data = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 4
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 6
  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 9
  }
];

function sortData() {
  var sortedData = {};
  data.forEach(sample => {
  // Need to check if the array for the sample has been created since we cannot "push" to "undefined".
    if (sortedData[sample.a]) {
      sortedData[sample.a].push(sample);
    } else {
      sortedData[sample.a] = [sample];
    }
  });
  return sortedData;
}

console.log(sortData());
```